# Crystal Report does not show all columns of tables with LINQ connection

Tags: c#, linq, crystal-reports

I have created a program in C# with LINQ connection from SQL SERVER. I want to generate a report of this program with crystal report in Visual Studio 2012. I chose .Net objects in data source and selected  tables. When I select fields, it only show columns of tables that are primary key and indexed and no other columns. 
Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share what you have done so far with your code.

Comment: I done with wizard and don't need to code. I done it from Add new Items of project menu in visual studio and select Crystal report and then from page appear, must select data source from three option.